# How can I make only the selected object change to wireframe view?

Tags: 3d-view, wireframe

When I select an object and go to wireframe view, all objects go to wireframe. I want only the selected object to go to wireframe. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference, here's a screenshot of the same thing in Blender 2.83. Note you have to both check the wireframe box and set the display to "wire".

[image: WireframeObjectDisplay]

Answer (score 1):

On viewing objects in "wireframe" mode ,all objects go to wireframe by default.

In order to view ,wireframe for a selected object in "other modes" , ***check "wire" under the objects panel.***

[image]